# Magento 2 ui form component switcherConfig value expression

Tags: uicomponent, magento2.2.2, ui-form, rules

Doe anyone know at all if possible to have expression to evaluate a value in rules E.G :

```
<switcherConfig>
   <rules>
       <rule name="0">
         <value>EXPRESSION HERE</value>
         <actions>
           <action name="0">
               <target>vendor_module_form_edit.vendor_module_form_edit.general.field</target>
               <callback>show</callback>
               </action>
             </actions>
         </rule>
     </rules>
  <enabled>true</enabled>
</switcherConfig>
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently the switcher.js does not have any feature for expressions evaluations.